# Built-in MacBook screen recognized as a separate display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, audio, mojave

I have a late 2011 Macbook Pro 13 inch. It was running macOS High Sierra and decided to try installing macOS Mojave using this patcher tool: http://dosdude1.com/mojave/. I successfully installed it with all its' kext files to be able to work with my Mac.

Unfortunately, not everything worked perfectly. My built-in screen is showing up as an external display, which is causing it to always be open, even when it is in sleep mode. I also cannot dim the screen using the buttons on the keyboard.

Another problem is that my internal speakers are not showing up in my sound preferences. I tried plugging in headphones in the headphone jack, but that didn't work either. When I boot up the computer, there is a chime that plays, so that is a good sign that the speakers work.

If there is anyone that can suggest any additional kext files I can download to make the display and audio work properly, that would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whalro! Unfortunately, I can’t supply any kexts. Most Macs made in 2011 or before aren’t fully compatible with the patcher. My 2011 iMac has all of the same issues. I still haven’t came across any fixes yet. By the way, have you tried using the patch updater? I hope I was helpful! Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I updated the patcher, and even tried to re-install the kexts, but I still get the same problem.